# Showing the multiplication operator only has closed range for characteristic functions

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces, orthonormal

For each $g\in L^\infty$, let $M_g:L^2\rightarrow L^2$ be the multiplication operator defined by $M_g(f)=fg$.  Show that the range of $M_g$ is closed if and only if $g$ is a characteristic function.

I'm not sure how to approach this.  For the backwards direction I tried to assume that the range of $M_{1_A}$ is closed, by showing $M_{1_A}^{-1}:range(M_{1_A})\rightarrow L^2$ is continuous.  But I couldn't get anywhere in trying to prove to $M_{1_A}^{-1}$ maps convergent sequences to convergent sequences.  The other thought I had is that we use the Hilbert space properties of $L^2$, like the existence of an orthonormal basis  But I'm not sure how to use it here.

Comment: The statement you want to prove is very, very false. For example, $M_g$ is surjective (and thus has closed range) if $0<A\leq g \leq B <\infty$.

Comment: @PhoemueX Why is $M_g$ surjective for all such functions?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan It's even invertible. For the surjectivity, let $h\in L^2$ and put $f := h/g$. Then $|f|\le |h|/A$ and thus $f\in L^2$. Moreover, $M_gf = h$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$g \equiv 2$ is not a characteristic function but $M_g$ has closed range (namley whole of $L^{2}$) in this case.

Comment: Is the other direction at least true, i.e. the multiplication operator of a characteristic function has closed range?

Comment: Yes, that part is true. If $M_g(f_n) \to h$ where $g=I_E$ then $f_nI_E=f_nI_E I_E \to hI_E=M_g(h)$ so $h=M_g(h)$ which proves that the range is closed.